# Evaluate bounds of a Path (created only with a String)

Tags: java, swt

I would like to draw a String with Path and center it inside a Rectangle. 
The problem is that I don't know how to evaluate the size/bounds of the path.
I have tried to use the corresponding size of the the same String drawn in a normal way (gc.drawString...) and after using gc.textExtent(String), but apparently the two size are different so the result is not ok....

Do you have any idea how to evaluate the size of the path in order to draw it centered in a rectangle?

The problem is that drawing a string with path is bigger that drawing a string in the normal way. You can verify it with this simple code.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWTException;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Path;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ShapeText 
{
    static Path path=null;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        Font font = new Font(display, "Times", 50, SWT.BOLD);
        final Color blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
        final Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);

        try {

        } catch (SWTException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            display.dispose();
            return;
        }

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() 
        {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) 
            {   


                path = new Path(display);
                e.gc.setFont(font);
                path.addString("Path is different", 0, 0, font);
                GC gc = e.gc;
                gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
                gc.setTextAntialias(SWT.ON);

                gc.setForeground(blue);
                gc.setBackground(blue);
                //gc.fillPath(path);
                gc.drawPath(path);
                gc.setForeground(red);
                gc.drawString("Path is different", 0, 0,true);
            }
        });

        shell.setSize(530,120);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        path.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see the String drawn with Path (in blue) is longer than the other (in red)...

Comment: The documentation isn't very helpful, but if you examine the output closely (at the pixel level) it _appears_ the outline is being drawn offset to the right 1 pixel and up 1 pixel, and also each outline glyph is 1 pixel wider than the base character.  This would be more obvious if you drew the blue outline on top of the red glyphs.  If your intent is to produce a true outline _around the outside_ of each red glyph, that API may not be what you're looking for.  You may have to outline each character individually, and scale the outline so it lies outside the base glyph.

Comment: Hi Jim, and thank you for your answer, My intent is just to draw the string with Path because I need to draw it in a high resolution and after scale it, and the result seems better than drawing in the normal way. If what you said it's true, all I need to do is to scale by 1 pixel the Path and to translate it one pixel to left and one pixel down? Is that what you mean? How can I scale it of just one pixel?

Comment: I have a typesetting background from the '80s, but how to accomplish your goals is outside my area of programming expertise (I do mostly backend/DB). Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, I appreciated your attempt, it's a good one! Thank you I will try to implement it! ;)

Comment: The strange thing is that the difference between the normal String drawing and the Path also spends on the font size, I'm trying to understand the "factor" that I can use to scale the path but it's very hard, it seems it's a not linear function... :(